# Why does this wire in my ceiling fan switch lead to my light switch?

Tags: switch, light

I'm having trouble figuring out which wires are which for my 3 wire light dimmer set up for my ceiling fan's light bulb. What is the wire on the bottom screw of the switch pictured? That's the ceiling fan's switch (not it's light), and that wire leads to somewhere in my light dimmer, but I'm not sure where. Before, that wire led to a single prong Cooper light switch, shoved into the top terminal with another wire.

[image: Circled is the wire I'm asking about. The top terminal is connected to the red wire.]

Edit: Here is the wiring of the box:
[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back of the box please?

Comment: Sure thing. Edited my post with it @ThreePhaseEel

Comment: Please ignore the wiring to the switch I'm holding, it's wrong.

Comment: I went ahead and put the mystery wire from the fan switch as the common wire to the light switch, with the two other black wires as travelers. That was fine and dandy, and the light worked, but it would could a noticeable buzz in some electronics (NOT THE LED BULB) and cause a fire alarm to beep. Is this bad?

Comment: @James -- yeah, I'd unhook what you did and post photos of the other boxes involved if this is a multi-way setup